# make the last div of a page fill the remainder of the browser height

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've seen other answers around, but they either didn't work, or involved JavaScript. Could some sort of @media query solve this?

I have a JSFiddle to show an example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/e4VWL/

You can see `<footer class="copyright">` looks awkward because the left border on `.wrapper` isn't reaching the bottom of the page.

I want to find a CSS only solution to make the final `div` occupy the remainder of the height of the page for the browser viewing.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gauravgr/E5JLh/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your body, html, and wrapper elements a height of 100%.

```
body,html,#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e4VWL/5/)

Comment: I actually tried that earlier on my live website, but couldn't get it going, but saw it was actually working in the fiddle. Just spent about an hour playing with a few other things along with your solution, and got it to work, among multiple other fixes. Thank you.